# How to find Flash and RAM usage using map file in Arduino in comparison with SEGGER RISC-V map file

Tags: arduino, heap-memory, riscv, segger-jlink, map-files

While building and uploading a code in **Arduino IDE**, it will generate a .map file. Usually in **SEGGER RISC-V**, it will generate **.map**,**.bin**,**.elf** & **.hex** files after building the code. In Arduino IDE also, it  will generate the same above files.
If we compare Arduino IDE generated **.map** file with **SEGGER RISC-V** generated **.map** file, the **SEGGER RISC-V** generated **.map** file contains the exact amount of RAM and Flash Memory usage.[image]
But Arduino generated **.map** file doesn't contain any of the details based on memory.

So how can i able to get values of **.bss**,**.text**,**.data**, **stack** and **heap size** from **.map** file of Arduino